# Cual es mi error?

Tags: java

Estoy a prendiendo a usar el entorno netbeans y java. No entiendo que esta mal el método que uso o que no se convierte a entero. Agradecería su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo modifica tu pregunta y cambia el titulo a algo mas descriptivo a tu error

Comment: Hola Raul. También es preferible evitar usar imágenes a favor de simplemente incluir el código como texto directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: @sstan ciertamente, Raul Alberto te invito a leer este enlace. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Muchas gracias, olvide que hay normativas en el foro, lo tendré en cuenta, la siguiente vez.

Comment: Raul, aunque hayas encontrado la respuesta tienes que modificar la pregunta para que tenga un formato adecuado. **No** lo dejes para la siguiente vez.  Sustituye la foto por el codigo en formato de texto. Y edita el titulo. Un saludo!

Comment: Viendo que la solución aceptada es cambiar una coma por un +, estoy votando para cerrar como error tipográfico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es bueno usar variables staticas si no van a ser algo como

```
public static final double PI = 3.14159265;
```

El problema es que el error no es la conversion, si no el parametro del metodo .showMessageDialog()

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"aaaaaaaa"+a,"bbbbbb"+b);//elimina las comas despues del null remplazalas por +
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"aaaaaaaa"+a+"bbbbbb"+b);
```

Comment: Errores de un programador nivel 1, jaja gracias siempre si fue eso, me estreso por horas de combinaciones estos argumentos.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que pones un `String` como argumento siendo que el tipo de parametro es `int` y ademas el son propios del Componente `JOptionPane`.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, new Object[]{"Parrafo 1", "Parrafo 2", "Parrafo 3"}, "Titulo",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

//Tipos
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION //Un simple "Aceptar"
JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION  //Botón de "Aceptar" y "Cancelar"
```

[Aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) tienes todos los parámetros del componente.